# use .net ui automation framework to capture user clicks of links in outlook application

Tags: microsoft-ui-automation

I'm using .net ui automation framework to capture user clicks of links when they are viewing a message in an outlook application.
The problem is that, I'm not able to get the link as an AutomationElement(as I can in a web page in IE window). I can only get the document pane as a whole.
Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I got it myself.
Though I'm not able to get the link directly, I can locate the link and get it from the `TextPattern` of the document element.
Suppose `element` is the document element that directly gets the focus or clicked:

```
if (element.Current.LocalizedControlType == "document")
{
    var point = new System.Windows.Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
    object textPattern;
    if (element.TryGetCurrentPattern(TextPattern.Pattern, out textPattern))
    {
        var range = ((TextPattern)textPattern).RangeFromPoint(point);   //it's an empty range
        var e = range.GetEnclosingElement();    //get the enclosing AutomationElement
        if (e.Current.LocalizedControlType == "link" || e.Current.LocalizedControlType == "hyperlink")
        {
            //use e
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code you use to register for the capture of link clicks?

Comment: @Jeff: seems the framework does not provide a direct way to let you listen to global click events. in my application using focus change event is just enough (`Automation.AddAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler`). if you want to capture only clicks, you can capture global click events yourself using windows hook, then use `AutomationElement.FromPoint` to get the AutomationElement under the mouse.